# React typescript - using const to call api data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've just started to learn react, and I'm very new to it. Right now I was trying to call some data from free currency conversion API.
When I'm calling the api, it returns something like this:

```
{
    "AUD_NZD": 1.089788
}
```

or

```
{
    "USD_AUD": 1.404502
}
```

As you can see, the very top level of the returned data is changing as I enter different money type. And here is my code to fetch the data:

```
const API_INFO = primary + '_' + secondary;
const API_CALL = await fetch(`https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=${API_INFO}&compact=ultra`);
const API_DATA = await API_CALL.json();
const result = API_DATA.API_INFO;
```

But the const result is actually returning undefined, as API.DATA.API_INFO does not exist in the returned data.

Is there a way to use dynamic values of API_INFO to actually fetch the conversion rate only?

Cheers.

Comment: See the linked question's answers for details. Basically: `const result = API_DATA[API_INFO];`. (Side note: In JavaScript, using ALL CAPS for variables is extremely uncommon [even when they're local constants].)

Comment: Sweet, Its working! Thanks for the fast response. And I will fix the caps. Cheers.